# jQuery Validate plugin not checking non dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin to validate a form date. I've set the rules up for the input element to validate as required and as a date. The only rule though that seems to be firing is the required one as I can put any thing in (text, numbers etc) and it passes validation. Only if the input field is blank does it show an error.

Here's my script:

```
        $(function() {
            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    entryDate: {
                        required: true,
                        date: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    entryDate:{
                        required: "A Date is required",
                        date: "Please enter a valid date"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

which is inside a script tag.

Here's my test form:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form1">
            <input id="entryDate" name="entryDate" class="date" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Why are non dates being accepted?

I've included the scripts in the file (jQuery and Validate) and both are loading ok.

Comment: This is explained in the documentation: ***Return true, if the value is a valid date. Uses JavaScripts built-in Date to test if the date is valid, and does therefore no sanity checks. Only the format must be valid, not the actual date, eg 30/30/2008 is a valid date. Works with text inputs!*** This means that anaything that doesn't return "Invalid Date" when passed to the `Date` constructor will validate.

Comment: As test input I tried "abc" and "123" both of these entries appear to have passed validation. Based on comment is this expected and normal behaviour for a date validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Quote OP:** "Why are non dates being accepted?"
>
> **Quote OP comment:** "As test input I tried 'abc' and '123' both of these
>   entries appear to have passed validation. Based on comment is this
>   expected and normal behaviour for a date validation?"

Your code, exactly as you've posted it, is working as expected.  As you can see, `abc` and `123` do *not* pass validation...

http://jsfiddle.net/zsCM3/

You also do not need to use inline `class="date"` when you've already declared `date: true` within the `rules` option.  Although this has no bearing on the issue, demo is working the same in both cases...

http://jsfiddle.net/TWEXJ/

---

**EDIT:**

Confirmed that in Chrome (24.0.1312.52), an entry of `123` is indeed passing validation.  I tried the jsFiddle with both jQuery 1.8.3 and 1.9.0.

Comment: Hi - thanks just reviewed - thank you. However in CHrome the script as still accepts 123 as a valid date. I retested it in firefox and everything works well and tested as expected. I know chrome only validated us dates but didnt know this could be a potential issue with chrome as well. Thank you

Comment: @Ray, Since the posted code is working, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: @sparky- sorry always forget not to press the return key when adding a comment as it sends to early - completed comment as above. Appears a browser issue - Not sure how to resolve from here so will accept it works everywhere else and move on...thank you.

Comment: @Ray... that's really odd.  In my Chrome, `123` passes validation but `abc` does not.  This may be worthy of a bug report to the plugin's author.